# struct in header file 1 needed in header file 2, how do I do that?

Tags: c

I have a struct that I use in header file1. I now also need that struct in header file2 because it is used in function prototypes. I have included header file1 in header file2, but this give a lot of complaints of redefition of types after compiling? Is there a straightforward way to do it? I have googled about nested header files but this gives me rather complicated articles. I was wondering if there is a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure there is. Use [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard).

```
file1.h

#ifndef FILE1_H
#define FILE1_H

/* Define everything here. */

#endif
```

This way you can include file1.h over and over. In particular, you should always use include guards if a header *defines* things.

As a side note, if you don't need the details of the struct (that is, it should be an opaque type), you can use an incomplete type and just say `struct yourstruct;` at the top.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your header files are not guarded with include guards to prevent redefinitions. They should be

```
//header.h
#ifndef SOME_LONG_UNIQUE_NAME
#define SOME_LONG_UNIQUE_NAME

//header contents here

#endif
```

As a side note, you don't need all the header and struct definition just to declare function arguments. A forward declaration is enough.

```
struct C; //not including C.h
struct C* f(struct C* p);
```

This decreases code coupling and accelerated compilation

Answer (score 0):

Header file 1:

```
#ifndef HEADERFILE1_H
#define HEADERFILE1_H

//...
#endif
```

Header file 2:

```
#ifndef HEADERFILE2_H
#define HEADERFILE2_H

#include "headerfile1.h"

//...
#endif
```

Comment: Thank you all, that was helpful, it works. I do have an remaining question however. The problem is created by the fact that a header file is included twice, both in the header file where it is include and in the sourcefile that calls both header files. If so, the code from header file1 is simply included twice, so should you then put the guards around all the code in your header file1?

Comment: Yes. All headers should be guarded like this so that you don't have to care as much who includes what. It gets tricky when there's circular references, but that's nothing a bit of forward declaration can't handle.